# Spring Boot images uploading and serving

Tags: spring, image, spring-boot, file-upload, static-content

I'm making new Spring Boot app and want to be able to store and serve images, I want images to be stored in applications directory:
[image]

this is what uploading looks like for now:

```
@PostMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String upload(@RequestPart String title, @RequestPart MultipartFile img) throws IOException{
    String imgName = img.getOriginalFilename();
    Post p = new Post();
    p.setTitle(title);
    p.setImageName(imgName);
    postService.add(p);
    File upl = new File("images/" + imgName);
    upl.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(upl);
    fout.write(img.getBytes());
    fout.close();
    return "ok";
}
```

this is how I want to get images

```
<img th:src="@{'images/' + ${post.imageName}}"/>
```

for now I get 404 and when I want to view some images in directory I get

```
Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file
```

how should I do it to make it work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Per default your Spring Boot application serves [*static* content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) - in your case images - found at following locations:

- /static
- /public
- /resources
- /META-INF/resources

So usually, `static/images/` would perhaps be the place where Thymeleaf should expect the *static* images which have to be delivered for rendering. But since this place is about *static* content and since it is in general a bad idea to  save uploaded (dynamic) content inside your application I would recommend to **DON'T do that**. Did you think about what happens if your application is redeployed or moved to another machine? Your would have to backup / move the images in a cumbersome way. There are better solutions, storing the upload content at a separate location outside your app (which could for example be configurable and also reused by multiple instances) or even use a database to store image data. That would also enable handling images in a transactional context (e.g. isolation & rollbacks).

But If you now want to still store it inside your app, your can extend the locations by adding places to search for (actually *static* content). Although the answer of Ajit and even the documentation still gives the advice to extend your own `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, I personally would tend to implement [WebMvcConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) instead, because the former is deprecated.

In this case it should look like:

```
@Configuration
public class AdditionalResourceWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:images/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To access image from  your `images folder`,

[image]

You need to override `addResourceHandlers` method of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:images/");
    }
}
```

After that you need add `/` before images in URL like this:

```
<img th:src="@{'/images/' + ${post.imageName}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

You can store external files in a folder named `/static` in the same directory as your jar and spring will scan them by default. So if you have `static/images/` you can reference your images with:

`<img th:src="@{/images/img.ext}"/>`

So you would want to use `new File("/static/images/" + imgName);`