# spring boot - serving images from folder outside src

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a folder named `uploads` which is at the same level as `src` folder. I upload images to this folder. 
Then I added the following configuration to be able to serve the images in thymeleaf:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/uploads/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/","/../../uploads/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

I try to serve the images in Thymeleaf like this:

```
<img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="#" th:src="@{'/uploads/' + ${photo}}" alt="">
```

where `${photo}` is the name file name.

However I get the following error:

```
The resource path [/../../uploads/rtf_vtvsq1r12q.png] has been normalized to [null] which is not valid.
```

Apparently the path in my configuration is wrong. Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is missing **`file`**. Add below configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:resources/", "file:uploads/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

[*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651119/spring-boot-images-uploading-and-serving) you get details.

Comment: excellent! do you have any link to documentaions about this specific syntax file:uploads?