# Spring Boot/Thymeleaf : Processed image not displaying in browser, despite image existing, path seeming to be correct

Tags: java, spring, image, thymeleaf

I'm very new to Spring Boot.

I have programmed an API with a simple front end which accepts a square image (ideally: 900x900px), and a String of words to add on the image.
The API successfully adds the inputted text onto the inputted image.
The processed image with text is saved to the resources/static/final_posts folder.

The problem is, despite the processed image being created, the browser will not serve it. Instead, there is one of those small "missing image" icons being displayed, along with the alt text.

This is the Thymeleaf expression supposed to display the image:

```
<img th:src="@{/final_posts/{filename}(filename=${filename})}" alt="image">
```

I used inspect element on the browser to check the generated src path, and it indeed seems to be correct.

The error I get in the browser when specifically requesting the path of the image just generated is that the image does not exist.

However, when I request previously-generated images directly in the URL, it seems to work well.

Each processed image is given a unique UUID I am serving into the filename in the Thymeleaf expression.

Also, weirdly enough, sometimes, if I waited around 5 minutes, and refreshed the browser, the image would appear perfectly, but not always.

I really don't understand what is going on.

A few noob hypotheses I have:

1. Is there some kind of "lock" on the image just processed? (similar to how you can't manipulate an oepn word document's xml).
2. Is the uploadIndex.html template being served before the image has been processed? I don't think it is the case, but maybe there's something I'm not seeing...
3. Something else

I don't have Spring Security enabled.
I've been searching for a fix for days, and can't wrap my head around how something as simple as displaying a dynamically changing image isn't working here.

I have my project code in this repository: https://github.com/RealMaximeCaloz/REST_API

To use the code, just start the server up with
`mvn clean spring-boot:run`

Then go to localhost:8080 , enter a String of words, upload an image (probably best to try my images, which are in the "uploads" folder, at the topmost level).
Hit submit, and the image should normally appear, but it isn't appearing for me.

Does anyone have an idea why the image is not displaying, or has a fix?

I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Since Thymeleaf is a template processing framework which only replaces kind of palceholder values with the processed ones you can simply check within your browser whether the requested image path is proper or not. That being said, the processed path should match your hard coded one which you claim is working.

Comment: I tried it again. I obtained the "missing image" icon. I inspected the HTML, and the path seemed correct. I did a right click --> Duplicate element on the <img> tag, and below and behold, the correct image is displayed for the duplicated element, which should be exactly the same as the thymeleaf-generated element...but the thymeleaf-generated element does not display the image.... Any idea?

Comment: That sounds very strange, even impossible. When the images have the exact same path, the browser calls the same entpoint to retrieve them. The backend doesn't know whether the path was hardcoded or created by Thymeleaf. Can you paste the HTML created by Thymeleaf?

Comment: That's why I'm losing my mind hahaha. The Thymeleaf-generated tag: <img src="/final_posts/final_post539d3286-f821-4125-b83c-a8b5c1883e5d.jpg" alt="image"> . The duplicated tag (which works): <img src="/final_posts/final_post539d3286-f821-4125-b83c-a8b5c1883e5d.jpg" alt="image">

Comment: Hey, I figured it out! Apparently, you shouldn't put dynamically generated images into the static folder. So, I created a folder on the top level, where generated images are placed. I also had to extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. 
 This link was very helpful : 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651119/spring-boot-images-uploading-and-serving?fbclid=IwAR2yiYCtiDV7Krvep4aZblupEm7WdfOO21b-Fe00IzfDCy1hd3FBSJuVXuE